# snapshot.connectionState stuck on 'waiting' and login view only logs in when I hot restart. I've tried everything

Tags: flutter, dart

When trying to establish connection the circular progress bar just keeps on going because the connection state is stuck on waiting.

`NotesView` :

```dart
import 'package:app_two/lib/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/enums/menu_action.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/services/auth/crud/notes_service.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NotesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotesView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotesView> createState() => _NotesViewState();
}

class _NotesViewState extends State<NotesView> {
  late Future _myFuture;
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  String get userEmail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email!;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _notesService = NotesService();
    getGet() async {
      return await _notesService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail);
    }

    _myFuture = getGet();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _notesService.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // getGet() async {
  //   return await _notesService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail);
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Main UI'),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton<MenuAction>(
            onSelected: (value) async {
              switch (value) {
                case MenuAction.logout:
                  final shouldLogout = await showLogOutDialog(context);
                  if (shouldLogout) {
                    await AuthService.firebase().logOut();
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      loginRoute,
                      (_) => false,
                    );
                  }
              }
            },
            itemBuilder: (context) {
              return const [
                PopupMenuItem<MenuAction>(
                  value: MenuAction.logout,
                  child: Text('Logout'),
                ),
              ];
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _myFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              print(snapshot.connectionState);
              return const Text('Your notes will appear here');
            case ConnectionState.none:
              print(snapshot.connectionState);
              return const Text('None');
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              print(snapshot.connectionState);
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            case ConnectionState.active:
              print(snapshot.connectionState);
              return const Text('Active');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> showLogOutDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Sign out'),
          content: const Text('Are you sure you want to sign out?'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
                child: const Text('Cancel')),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                },
                child: const Text('Logout'))
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((value) => value ?? false);
  }
}
```

`NotesService` :

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;
import 'crud_exceptions.dart';

class NotesService {
  Database? _db;

  List<DatabaseNote> _notes = [];

  final _notesStreamController =
      StreamController<List<DatabaseNote>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<DatabaseNote>> get allNotes => _notesStreamController.stream;

  Future<DatabaseUser> getOrCreateUser({required String email}) async {
    try {
      final user = await getUser(email: email);
      return user;
    } on CouldNotFindUser {
      final createdUser = await createUser(email: email);
      return createdUser;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _cacheNotes() async {
    final allNotes = await getAllNotes();
    _notes = allNotes.toList();
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> updateNote({
    required DatabaseNote note,
    required String text,
  }) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    //make sure note exists
    await getNote(id: note.id);
    //update db
    final updatesCount = await db.update(noteTable, {
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedwithCloudColumn: 0,
    });
    if (updatesCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotUpdateNote();
    } else {
      final updatedNote = await getNote(id: note.id);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == updatedNote.id);
      _notes.add(updatedNote);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return updatedNote;
    }
  }

  Future<Iterable<DatabaseNote>> getAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(noteTable);

    return notes.map((noteRow) => DatabaseNote.fromRow(noteRow));
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> getNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(
      noteTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    if (notes.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindNote();
    } else {
      final note = DatabaseNote.fromRow(notes.first);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return note;
    }
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final numberOfdeletions = await db.delete(noteTable);
    _notes = [];
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    return numberOfdeletions;
  }

  Future<void> deleteNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      noteTable,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    if (deletedCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteNote();
    } else {
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> createNote({required DatabaseUser owner}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    //Make sure owner exists in database withthe correct id
    final dbUser = await getUser(email: owner.email);
    if (dbUser != owner) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    }

    const text = '';
    //create the note
    final noteId = await db.insert(noteTable, {
      userIdColumn: owner.id,
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedwithCloudColumn: 1,
    });

    final note = DatabaseNote(
      id: noteId,
      userId: owner.id,
      text: text,
      isSyncedWithCloud: true,
    );

    _notes.add(note);
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);

    return note;
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> getUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (results.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    } else {
      return DatabaseUser.fromRow(results.first);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> createUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      throw UserAlreadyExists();
    }
    final userId = await db.insert(userTable, {
      emailColumn: email.toLowerCase(),
    });

    return DatabaseUser(id: userId, email: email);
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser({required String email}) async {
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      userTable,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (deletedCount != 1) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteUser();
    }
  }

  Database _getDatabaseorThrow() {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      return db;
    }
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      await db.close();
      _db = null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _ensureDbIsOpen() async {
    try {
      await open();
    } on DatabaseAlreadyOpenException {
      //empty
    }
  }

  Future<void> open() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenException();
    }
    try {
      await _ensureDbIsOpen();
      final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final dbPath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
      final db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
      _db = db;
      //create user table
      await db.execute(createUserTable);
      //create note table
      await db.execute(createNoteTable);
      await _cacheNotes();
    } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException {
      throw UnableToGetDocumentDirectory();
    }
  }
}

@immutable
class DatabaseUser {
  final int id;
  final String email;

  const DatabaseUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
  });
  DatabaseUser.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        email = map[emailColumn] as String;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person, ID = $id, email= $email';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

class DatabaseNote {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String text;
  final bool isSyncedWithCloud;

  DatabaseNote({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.text,
    required this.isSyncedWithCloud,
  });

  DatabaseNote.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        userId = map[userIdColumn] as int,
        text = map[textColumn] as String,
        isSyncedWithCloud =
            (map[isSyncedwithCloudColumn] as int) == 1 ? true : false;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Note, ID = $id, userId = $userId, isSyncedWithCloud = $isSyncedWithCloud, tesxt = $text';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseNote other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

const dbName = 'notes.db';
const noteTable = 'note';
const userTable = 'user';
const idColumn = 'id';
const emailColumn = 'email';
const userIdColumn = 'user_id';
const textColumn = 'text';
const isSyncedwithCloudColumn = 'is_synced_with_cloud';
const createUserTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
        "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "email" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
        );''';
const createNoteTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "note" (
          "id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
          "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
          "text"    TEXT,
          "is_synced_with_cloud"    INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
          FOREIGN KEY("user_id") REFERENCES "user"("id"),
          PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
        );''';
```

`main.dart` :

```dart
import 'package:app_two/lib/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:app_two/views/login_view.dart';
import 'package:app_two/views/notes_view.dart';
import 'package:app_two/views/register_view.dart';
import 'package:app_two/views/verify_email_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phoenix/flutter_phoenix.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        ),
        home: const HomePage(),
        routes: {
          loginRoute: (context) => const LoginView(),
          registerRoute: (context) => const RegisterView(),
          notesRoute: (context) => const NotesView(),
          verifyEmailRoute: (context) => const VerifyEmailView(),
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: AuthService.firebase().initialize(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.done:
            final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
            if (user != null) {
              if (user.isEmailVerified) {
                return const NotesView();
              } else {
                return const VerifyEmailView();
              }
            } else {
              return const LoginView();
            }

          default:
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

// class RestartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
//   RestartWidget({required this.child});

//   final Widget child;

//   static void restartApp(BuildContext context) {
//     context.findAncestorStateOfType<_RestartWidgetState>()?.restartApp();
//   }

//   @override
//   _RestartWidgetState createState() => _RestartWidgetState();
// }

// class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
//   Key key = UniqueKey();

//   void restartApp() {
//     setState(() {
//       key = UniqueKey();
//     });
//   }

//   @override
//   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//     return KeyedSubtree(
//       key: key,
//       child: widget.child,
//     );
//   }
// }
```

`LoginView` :

```dart
import 'package:app_two/lib/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/utilities/show_error_dialog.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/services/auth/auth_exceptions.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phoenix/flutter_phoenix.dart';

class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginView({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState();
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Login')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _email,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your email'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _password,
            obscureText: true,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            autocorrect: false,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your password'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final email = _email.text;
              final password = _password.text;
              try {
                AuthService.firebase().logIn(
                  email: email,
                  password: password,
                );
                var user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
                AuthService.firebase().reload();
                user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
                if (user?.isEmailVerified == true) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    notesRoute,
                    (route) => false,
                  );
                } else {
                  print(user);
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    verifyEmailRoute,
                    (route) => false,
                  );
                }
              } on UserNotFoundAuthException {
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  'User not found',
                );
              } on WrongPasswordAuthException {
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  'Wrong credentials',
                );
              } on GenericAuthException {
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  'Authentication error',
                );
              }
            },
            child: const Text("Login"),
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  registerRoute,
                  (route) => false,
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Not registered? Register here!'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After the user logs in I'm supposed to establish a connection and get a message when it is done.

`LoginView` is supposed to take the user to `NotesView` after the correct info but it always takes the user to verify email view regardless of what I input. `print(user)` returns null.

Comment: Your super.initState() should go at the beginning of the overridden methods, not the end.  And there's this: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: I've edited the code and done both these things as you'll see but it still doesn't work. I've tested both the UI and service codes but it seems the problem is from neither of them.

Comment: You've asked this question in multiple reddit threads and possibly multiple stack overflow threads.  Please don't do that again.

Comment: What do you mean? I asked this, just this once on stack overflow and I have two posts on reddit about this. One with the link to this post and another that only has the two functions i thought were giving me issues